# How to write HTML inside elements with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm beginning with Angular, and just wanted to make some tests with Ajax, retrieving a document into my page. It works perfectly, but then a new challenge appeared: I want to be able to add HTML inside a DOM element.

Normally, one would do that from a directive and the templates thingy. But I want to do it at runtime, using a controller.

This is my code:

```
$http.get("import.html").then(function(response){
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.innerHTML = response.data;
    angular.element("#div1").innerHTML(element);
        });
```

Maybe I'm not using correctly "angular.element"? I tried using document.getElementByID, but it doesn't work either. I receive correctly the information from the file, but I just don't find a way I can compile that HTML in runtime.

Any help with this?

edit for showing my full code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="miApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="mainmodule.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="controlador1">
      <div id="div1" ng-bind-html="myHtml" style="top:50px;left:50px">
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**
(tested all your examples, none worked for me, this is the last I used)

```
app.controller('controlador1', ["$scope", "$http", "$sce", "$compile", function($scope, $http, $sce, $compile) {

    $http.get("import.html").then(function(response) {

        var parent = angular.element("#div1");
var element = angular.element($sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
$compile(element)($scope);
parent.append(element);
    });


}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this, I have made use of `$sce`. It's a dependency injection of AngularJS, where it treats the HTML as safe to bind. You can read about it in [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) site. Please find below code and working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/wkm5vnjr/) for the raised concern:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <div>
        This is onload HTML
    </div>
    <div ng-bind-html="dynamicHtml"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.dynamicHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>This is dynamic HTML!!");
});
```

[Update]

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-bind-html="dynamicHtml"></div>`
```

**JS:**

```
$http.get("import.html").then(function (response) {
    $scope.dynamicHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data); //Assuming 'response.data' has the HTML string
});
```

Comment: Not working. I injected the $sce dependency and used your code with the response.data, but it just won't show anything.

Comment: where is it not working?can you show your js contents?

Comment: In this you shouldn't create dynamic `div` but that `div` should be existing in the HTML and should be bind with the model. As soon as the `model` gets updated the `div` will bind the HTML.  Look I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why, but now it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you want to compile your HTML if it contains any angular functionality at all (you need to declare '$compile' in your controller dependency list):

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$compile'],
   $scope, $sce, $compile) {

 $http.get("test.html")
  .then(function(response){
    var parent = angular.element("#div1");
    parent.append($compile(response.data) ($scope));
  });
}]);
```

if you are hell-bent on useing `innerHTML`, note that `angular.element("#div1")` is the same as `$("#div1")` in jQuery. So you need to write `angular.element("#div1")[0].innerHTML= ...`

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/p3TXhBppxXLAMwRzJSWF?p=preview

Comment: That's not working for me. No code works below the angular.element() methods, not even alerts. Something is wrong with that method I guess. Also, how should I use the $sce.trustAsHtml method?

Comment: Keeps the same way: nothing shows up in screen nor in console.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correctly angular. If you use angular, you don't harly ever have to use DOM selector.

Scope is binded with `ng-model` and `{{}}` on the view.

Now your answer. To print html on the view, you can do it in that way:

In controller:

```
$http.get("import.html").then(function(response){
   $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
});
```

In view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

And more easy way:

```
<ng-include="'url/import.html'"><ng-include>
```

That's it!!!

Comment: I know about the ng-include! This is just a test, you know. But no, your code doesn't work either. Nothing shows up in screen nor in console.

Comment: You did +1 to the worst solution. That's not a good way to work with angular. You should only use jquery selector into directives. But if you want to develop in that way...